# EmailExt- Jenkinsfile - HTML and CSS files are not embedded

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

EmailExt- Jenkinsfile - HTML and CSS files are not embedded

I am trying to attach html report in the email body and send the mail using **Email-ext** plugin.

```
 email-ext attachmentsPattern: "filePathToBeAttached", mimeType:'text/html', body: readFile("${env.WORKSPACE}/path_to_report.html"),to: acbd@gmail.com", subject:"test report"
```

But I could see plain HTML without proper formatting and absence of CSS styling in the email report sent.

Any help pls.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently working for me. HTML is properly formatted in the mail, in outlook. I'm not using any css.

```
            unsuccessful {
            emailext mimeType: 'text/html',
            subject: "${PROJECT_NAME} - Build # ${BUILD_NUMBER} - ${BUILD_STATUS}!",
            body: readFile("${env.WORKSPACE}/JenkinsMailBody.html"),
            from: 'noreply-jenkins@sofico.be',
            replyTo: 'noreply-jenkins@sofico.be',
            recipientProviders: [culprits(), requestor()]
            }
```